# How do I render all posts of the same category in same layout?

Tags: posts, categories

I have several posts that share the same layout but have different title and content.

This layout is different from that on the site.

I can use single.php to render them, but then ALL posts will have this layout.

If I add some category for this posts, could I render all post in this category in the same way?

I tried using category-{category-name}.php but it just rendered the page for this category.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you are talking about single post pages. The template hierarchy does not make provision for single templates according to the category a post belongs to, so `single-{$category}.php` does not exist.

To make `single-{$category}.php` work, we can make use of the `single_template` filter

```
add_filter( 'single_template', function ( $template )
{
    global $post;
    // Check if our post has our specific category
    if ( !has_category( 1, $post ) ) // Change to your specific category
        return $template;

    // Locate and load our single-{$category}.php template
    $locate_template = locate_template( 'single-my_category.php' ); // Change to your exact template name
    if ( !$locate_template ) 
        return $template;

    // single-my_category.php exists, load it
    return $locate_template;
});
```

You can now just create our own custom single template and use it for any single post that belongs to the specific category you need to target

Comment: It just works!!!

Answer (score 1):

The category templates are just for post archives listing you would need to do this within the single.php template.

You can use has_category()within the single.php template to detect if the post has the category. Then just include different files. eg:

```
if ( has_category( $category, $post ) ) {
    include "template-one.php";
} else {
    include "template-two.php";
}
```

Ref: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_category